# Is there any source for saying the first possuk of Shema quietly?

Tags: sources-mekorot, shema, loud-quiet

The Rema in OC 61(26) says the custom is to say the first possuk of the shema aloud. In this question [Sh'ma aloud but amida quietly](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8796/shma-aloud-but-amida-quietly)  Gershon Gold said that Shema is said aloud in unison and msh210 said "Sh'ma" is not said in unison in many synagogues, but is said aloud anyway.

In many shuls I have “heard” people saying the first possuk quietly or even inaudibly. Is there any source for saying it quietly?

Comment: I believe the Talmud Yerushalmi discusses this, or the Haichalot literature, but I'm not certain. I vaguely remember something about it in passing from reading a different book/article about differences in practices between Israel and Bavel.

Answer (score 1):

The [Aruch Hashulchan Orach Chaim 61:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A1%D7%90) says that the custom in the whole Jewish Diaspora is to say the first verse of Shema out loud.

> המנהג בכל תפוצות ישראל לאמר "שמע ישראל" בקול רם

The [Rama in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 61:26](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A1%D7%90) brings in the name of the Kol Bo that even if you say the entire Kriyas Shema quietly, you should still say the first verse out loud.

> יש נוהגים לקרות קריאת שמע בקול רם ויש נוהגים לקרותו בלחש. הגה: ומכל מקום יאמרו פסוק ראשון בקול רם וכן נוהגין (כל בו):‏

[I assert](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15176/is-there-any-source-for-saying-the-first-possuk-of-shema-quietly/17151#comment37566_15187) that there is no source for those who say it quietly.

Comment: This is clearly not universally practiced nowadays. I believe he is asking for a source to support those who _don't_.

Comment: However the Aruch HaShulchan says that this is the correct practice all over.

Comment: @GershonGold The Aruch HaShulchan was published over 100 years ago and lived on a different continent than most Jews nowadays.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I want to +8 or +9 that comment. Gershon, that was my point. He says that's the Minhag, meaning that's what people _do_ (ok, he also says it's what people _should_ do). But, in fact, nowadays that is demonstrably _not_ what people (deliberately) do. I was never taught that this was correct, and if I took an informal survey, I'd venture to guess that most people in my Shul who _do_ in fact do so, do it out of habit, not out of specific training. I could be wrong about that, but then how to account for all the many individuals who _don't_ recite it out loud?

Comment: Isn't OC 61:4 the more logical se'if to quote? Why quote 61:26?

Comment: @SethJ Thank you. I once asked a Rav, in his shul where shema was said quietly by everyone including him, how to say shema. He told me that the first possuk at least should be said aloud. I didn't have the chutzpah to ask him why he didn't follow his own advice.

Comment: +1. This _AHS_ seems the correct answer. He is one of the greatest sources of _halacha_ of his time, especially for _Ashk'nazim_. Couple this answer with a _S'faradic_ source, and you've got a complete answer to the question. If (as suggested by commenters above) the situation has changed in the past hundred years, there very likely *is no* source, and people are simply erring. (Of course, that's not certain.)

Comment: @msh210 I wasn't denying the AH's credibility as a posek. Just that his observations of the popular minhag may be dated, just as the Rama's observations or the Rambam's may be too. If a minhag has changed over time, that doesn't _neccasarily_ mean we should revive it. The question was asking about a current minhag. (I might add that the Tur, Shulchan Aruch and AH all bring this down as a minhag not as din.)

Comment: Gershon wrote: that this is the correct practice all over. This is simply incorrect. The AH wrote it is the __popular__ practice all over. One claim is normative and one is empirical.

Comment: Whoops, misread. Please disregard my parenthetical remark about _should_.

Comment: Gershon, this seems more like it _reinforces_ the question, rather than answers it. Perhaps you'd like to leave it as a comment instead?

Comment: The answer is that there is no source for those who say it quietly.

Comment: @GershonGold May I suggest you add that to your answer?

Comment: @GershonGold The absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that saying the pasook out loud when someone is davening their *amidah* could be distracting to them. In such a case, saying it out loud could be considered *[yohara](http://www.thejc.com/judaism/jewish-words/yuhara)*. I'm not sure if there is any written source backing me up, but now [Jahadut.SE](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15176/1059) has a source for it.

Comment: Most people say the _pasuk_ when no one's saying _sh'mone esre_.