# When and why did we stop to receive lashes on Yom Kippur as Shu"A prescribes?

Tags: halacha-theory, yom-kippur, lashes-malkos

[Shu"A Orach Hayim 607.6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.607?lang=he)

> **כל הקהל לוקים מלקות ארבעים אחר תפלת המנחה
>
>   שמתוך כך יתן אל לבו לשוב מעבירות שבידו:**
>   **הגה** ונהגו שהנלקה אומר וידוים בשעה שנלקה וכו'‏
>
> **All of the congregation receives 40 lashes after minchah, for from this one places on his heart to repent for his sins.**
>   RAMA: The custom is for the recipient of lashes to say confessions at the time he is lashed and the one who lashes says "and He who is merciful atones for sin", etc.

EDIT: *while many Rabbis and even certain groups turned it into a Minhag, it clearly appears that it is not the Halacha that obligates all, as it was once (as Rem"A agrees), and I never saw it performed in [most] Israeli Haredi communities.*

When and why did we stop following this Halachah?

Comment: Who is "we"? This isn't a halacha, it's a custom, which I don't believe spread to Ashkenazi Jewry, from which I assume you descend

Comment: @robev it must have spread to ashkenazi Jewry, otherwise the Rema wouldn’t talk about, or “correct” the shu”a about it

Comment: From both sides of the spectrum: I recall a lecture (on YouTube?) by R. Bentzion Musafi, of Iraqi descent and Kabbalah leaning, on the specific topic and practice of administering/receiving these lashes and [here’s](https://bshch.blogspot.com/2019/10/blog-post_759.html?m=1) a video of the Naroler Rebbe (of Belz background, IIRC) receiving “*malkos*”.

Comment: [Related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20396/1569)

Comment: To add to @robev’s comment, I know several Sefardi shuls which give lashes, as well as a form of each of the Arba Middos Beis Din.

Comment: Chabad still does it

Comment: @robev Please help me understand when a Seif in Shu"A is an obligating Halacha and when it is "just a Minhag"? My Q. was based on my understanding that unless stated explicitly as a Minhag it is an obligating Halachah.

Comment: @mroll interesting, how it is done? Does Aruch make it an obligating Halachah? Do ALL Chabadnikes do it?

Comment: I've heard that it is still common at Buchara diaspora Jews.

Comment: Fwiw, I've seen the now-[Naroler](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narol_(Hasidic_dynasty)) rebbe get lashed ערב יו״כ (before he was the rebbe). This custom is not dead.

Comment: @AlBerko https://www.colelchabad.org/pdfs/Tishrei_English.pdf page 34, paragraph beginning “it is customary”

Answer (score 2):

Never; at least in Israel many still do it. There even are kabbalistic intentions for (versions of) it, refer to e.g. the Sim Shalom or the Avodath Hakodesh siddurim.

Comment: 1. Sorry, who's "Israel Manu", because by "we" I mean the rest of the Jewish world. 2. Please provide sources and examples. Otherwise the answer is hardly informative. :(

Comment: Israel manu? Sources are included. You claim it is abandoned, you should provide evidence. In Israel it is well spread. These are not strong lashes, just small taps that do not hurt, by the way.

Comment: @AlBerko Plenty of American communities do this, too. The only ones I know of are Sefardi, though.

Comment: "Sim Shalom": [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddur_Sim_Shalom)?

Comment: The question seems to presume that actual lashes are required, is it your contention that this is incorrect and the halachos referenced actually refer to the symbolic lashes you reference? If not, on what basis would such symbolic lashes fulfill the obligation outlined above?

Comment: @msh210 This one: https://www.simshalom.co.il